# Calling Routing event url to equal all non existent pages

Tags: angular, angular7, router

So I'm trying to disable appheader and appfooter in my Angular application. This is for a 404 error page I'm creating for the app.

I have it the notfound page routed as

```
    const routes: Routes = [
      {path: '**', component: NotfoundComponent },
    ];
```

Here is my code:

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationStart } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  
})
export class AppComponent {
    showHead = false;
    showFooter = false;

    constructor(private router: Router) {
    // on route change to '/login', set the variable showHead to false
        router.events.forEach((event) => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
            // tslint:disable-next-line:no-string-literal
            if (event['url'] === '**') {
            this.showHead = false;
            this.showFooter = false;
            } else {
            // console.log("NU")
            this.showHead = true;
            this.showFooter = true;
            }
        }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my hook up to my app component:

```html
<app-header *ngIf="showHead"></app-header>
<div class="routeContainer" [@routeAnimation]="getDepth(myOutlet)">
    <main class="main">
        <router-outlet #myOutlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
    </main>
</div>
<app-footer *ngIf="showFooter"></app-footer>
```

I'm trying to make sure it doesnt show the header and footer on my 404 error page on my application.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to export the routes array like this:

`const routes: Routes = [...`

Then you can import that array into your app.component.ts file. That way, you can iterate over it and check the path variable at each index.

Alternatively, you could use an entirely different template for your NotFoundComponent that does not include your header and footer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

**app.component.ts**

```
isNotFound = false;
constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router)
{ }

ngOnInit(): void {
     this.router.events.pipe(
        filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe(event => {
        if (this.route.snapshot.firstChild.data.status) {
            this.isNotFound = true;
        }
    });
}
```

This will get the data notfound from ActivatedRoute which we can use and then configure out header footer

**router will be**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: '**', component: NotfoundComponentComponent , data: { status : 'notfound'}}
];
```

here notice the `data: { status : 'notfound'}` which we will use in our app component.

**app.component.html**

```
<app-header *ngIf="!isNotFound"></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>   
<app-footer *ngIf="!isNotFound"></app-footer>
```

Comment: Just encountered a bug in this answer. When I click on a router link to go back to the application the header and footer are now missing from that also.

Comment: it will not show that route has data `data: { status : 'notfound'}` status with value notfound and you can also check the data by doing `console.log(this.route.snapshot.firstChild.data.status)` in `ngOnInit` before `if (this.route.snapshot.firstChild.data.status) {` this.